# IIS Returning 400 Error

Tags: iis

I am checking accessing an IIS on a local system. When I deploy an application to the server and check locally using localhost and local IP it works fine. When I open the port it is listening on via my router and try to access via the router IP it always returns a 400 error. The router has been configured to forward the call the the system IS is on. I can test the port with a port checker and it is showing as being open. I read messages that indicated that the header may not be present and would cause this type of error if multiple app are deployed. I tried to put headers on the apps but no difference. I then cleared all the apps except the original one that comes with IIS. But still cannot access the app. Can someone indicate what I'm missing with the IIS configuration (as I'm feeling it must be IIS related).

Comment: Install Wireshark on the server to confirm your packet does arrive there first.